# Bind to a DataTemplate dynamically

Tags: c#, xaml, data-binding, windows-8, windows-runtime

I have a `ListBox` and multiple `DataTemplate`s, in separate files.

```
<ListBox ItemTemplate="{StaticResource ItemTemplate1}"/>
```

In the `Styles.xaml` file:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="ItemTemplate1">...</DataTemplate>

<DataTemplate x:Key="ItemTemplate2">...</DataTemplate>
```

I want to change the `ItemTemplate` of the `ListBox` depending on the type of object that's in its list.

Is there a way to access the separate `DataTemplate`s in the code-behind, so that I can bind to a property of my `Page`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way to do that without `TemplateSelector` is to specify DataType property and don't specify x:Key.

```
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type Type1}">...</DataTemplate>
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type Type2}">...</DataTemplate>
```

In this case appropriate DataTemplate will be automaticly applied in all places where property of specified type have been bound.

But I'd prefer to use `TemplateSelector`.

To access separated DataTemplate in code-behind you should first get resource dictionary:

```
var dict = new ResourceDictionary 
{Source = new Uri("/ProjectNamespace;component/Styles.xaml",  UriKind.Relative)};
```

Then you can get template:

```
var dataTemplate = (DataTemplate) dict["ItemTemplate1"];
```

Comment: FYI. WinRT DataTemplate class doesn't support DataType.

Answer (score 1):

Try this solution does pretty much what your trying to achieve:

*Applying Data Templates Dynamically by Type in WP7*

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/113152/Applying-Data-Templates-Dynamically-by-Type-in-WP7

Its based on WP7 but should work for you too.

Answer (score 0):

There is inbuilt support in WPF for your requirement. Start reading on [DataTemplateSelector](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datatemplateselector.aspx) to select the template at runtime based on certain criteria.